# What is wrong with this for loop - trying to fill array with Tweet object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Basically, I have a JSON response from the Twitter API containing a timeline. I am trying to fill and array with Tweet objects in a loop but the alert window tells me that after the loop the array is empty:

```
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *tweetJsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    for (int i = 0; i < [tweetJsonObjects count]; i++) {
        Tweet *tweet = [[Tweet alloc] init];
        tweet.userName = [[[tweetJsonObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        tweet.text = [[tweetJsonObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"text"];
        //[tweet.text gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
        tweet.userProfileImageUrl = [[[tweetJsonObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
        [tweets addObject:tweet];
    }

    NSString *x = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [tweets count]];
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                                      message:x
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
```

The Tweet object is very simple:

```
@interface Tweet : NSObject
{
    NSString *userName;
    NSString *text;
    NSString *userProfileImageUrl;
    UIImage *userProfileImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userProfileImageUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *userProfileImage;
@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is because you call `indexOfObject:` instead of `addObject:` - an innocent autocompletion bug.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change last line in for loop to:

```
[tweets addObject:tweet];
```

P.S. If `tweets` is your array

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does, because you are not adding the objects to any array...
Obviously you meant `[tweets addObject:tweet]` instead of `[tweets indexOfObject:tweet]`